# Transforming JSON from one structure to another

Tags: c#, json, object, dynamic

I have a scenario that I am trying to get my head around. I have some JSON that I mostly don't care about except for certain values. I simply want to extract these values and add them to a new object.

Here is the JSON I am starting from:

```
{
  "name": "Codex JJ",
  "component": {
    "Profile-1": {
      "id": "Profile",
      "type": "Person",
      "attributes": {
                "Hair-color": "blue",
      "Eye-color": "brown",
        "hair-color": "brown",
        "height": "170cm"
      },
      "status": {
        "employed": "true",
        "ethnic": "White"
      }
    },
    "Profile-2": {
      "id": "Profile",
      "type": "Person",
      "attributes": {
                "Hair-color": "blue",
      "Eye-color": "brown",
        "hair-color": "brown",
        "height": "170cm"
      },
      "status": {
        "employed": "true",
        "ethnic": "White"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to reconstruct it into this JSON:

```
{
    "name": "NEW JSON"
    "company": [
        {
            "Person": "new-person",
            "attributes": {
                "Hair-color": "blue",
                "Eye-color": "brown",
                "employed": "true",
                "ethnic": "White"
            },
        {
            "Person": "new-person",
            "attributes": {
                "Hair-color": "blue",
                "Eye-color": "brown",
                "employed": "true",
                "ethnic": "White"
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

What would be the best practice to implement this? Should I use the `dynamic` keyword to deserialize my incoming JSON? How exactly can I extract values and add them to my created C# objects to generate a whole new JSON structure?

Comment: 1- Your source json is weird. IMHO `"component": {` should be `"component": [` and 2- I would use .net classes instead dynamic types and automapper. Then back to json.

Comment: Yes they have very different structures @bradbury9 but its for cross compatibility reasons. I was thinking of using expando objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to transform the JSON and you don't need (or want) a formal object model to represent the data, you could use [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)'s [LINQ-to-JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) API (JObjects) to do it:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);

JObject newObj = new JObject(
    new JProperty("name", obj["name"]),
    new JProperty("company", new JArray(
        obj["component"]
            .Children<JProperty>()
            .Select(jp => new JObject(
                    new JProperty((string)jp.Value["type"], jp.Name),
                    new JProperty("attributes", jp.Value["attributes"])
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

json = newObj.ToString();
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zSWAL0

Answer (score 1):

Here is just another solution using jsonata (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Retyped.jsonata)

So the expression would be:

```
{
    "name": "NEW JSON",
    "company": $each($.component, function($v, $k){
    {"Person": "new-person",
    "attributes": {
            "Hair-color": $v.attributes.`Hair-color`,
                "Eye-color": $v.attributes.`Eye-color`,
                "employed": $v.status.employed,
                "ethnic": $v.status.ethnic
        }
    }
    })
}
```

Live demo: https://try.jsonata.org/6fpDBlo94

Comment: I found that JSONata is cool by itself, but Retuped.jsonata package seem to be inteded to run as part of Bridge.NET project which is kinda abandoned. So I starred a native C# port for JSONata: https://github.com/mikhail-barg/jsonata.net.native . Most crucial features are already implemented