# How to change the names of some elements of a JSON string in c#

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

I have a JSON string that I receive from a service call that has the following format:

```
{
  "DataKEY": [
    {
      "value": {
        "timestamp": "2022-10-26T05:00:00Z",
        "value": 0.0
      }
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "timestamp": "2022-10-26T06:00:00Z",
        "value": 0.0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I change just the node names of the middle `"value"` to obtain the following output to send to another service:

```
{
  "DataKEY": [
    {
      "KEY": {
        "timestamp": "2022-10-26T05:00:00Z",
        "value": 0.0
      }
    },
    {
      "KEY": {
        "timestamp": "2022-10-26T06:00:00Z",
        "value": 0.0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to change the first level of nodes with the name `"value"` to a given `"KEY"` in the response string, I tried using `string.Replace("value", "KEY")` but that replaces the inner level as well.

How can I change only the first level of nodes?

Comment: Since it is obviously JSON, you should rather transform it from one schema to the other instead of mucking around with the string representation. Admittedly, the schema isn't optimal with a `value` object having a `value` property.

Comment: I'm confused, because the "expected output" does not match your explanation. Your explanation states that only the first match should be replaced, but the expected output has all matches replaced.

Comment: See if [Transforming JSON from one structure to another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55531295/205233) helps.

Comment: Only the first match in each response. Notice how the "value: 0.0" is unchanged, yet the KEY has been changed. @knittl

Comment: Yes, it was a JSON jObject that had been converted to String. Would this change be better to do before converting to string? Sorry, I am new to this. @Filburt

Comment: So you're replacing multiple instances, not only the first one. Filburt has the only sensible solution: parse from JSON, transform to new schema, serialize to JSON.

Comment: @Bash Depending on the class/object maybe there's no need for transformation at all. Please add more details about the source of this JSON.

Comment: This JSON was returned after making an API call to the KEY value I am trying to add back. I am using Newtonsoft.Json to then parse the response to a jObject and then later a jToken object and finally a string @Filburt

Comment: Try something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tm8iYs Note that I had to complete your input to make it a valid JSON string ;)

Comment: Will give this a try, everything looks good beside the null value, is there a way to get rid of this? I ask because the POST request requires a certain format to work. Thank you so much! @ChrisSchaller

Comment: Oops, how lazy of me: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YUsRn8 In the serializer settings, set `NullValueHandling` to `Ignore` . Sorry, that was the whole point of why I did it that way ;)

Comment: Voting to re-open because "first string" is a misleading duplicate, this isn't first string at all, in-fact the solution is to not use string manipulation at all, I am genuinely interested myself to see other solutions to this issue

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will give this new solution a try now! @ChrisSchaller

Answer (score 0):

When the string represents a JSON data response then you will find it easier to manipulate the names of the properties or the *structure* of the object graph by first deserializing the data transforming the data to the desired output, then serialising the transformed object back into a string.

If we only need to change the names of some elements, you could use a JSON reader and writer process to step through the file or we can take advantage of some serialization tricks to avoid the transformation step.

We can configure the serialization provider to *omit null valued properties* which means we can provide 2 properties on a class definition that will be mapped to the same internal backing field, in the example below I have mapped a second property to the inner `Key` value, this only has a *setter* making it *write-only*. This way any deserialization process can write to it via `Key` or `Value` named property, but in the serialization process the `Value` property will *always* return null and can be omitted from the output:

*this is the important aspect and probably the only scenario I've ever used a **write-only** property:*

```
public DataKeyValue Key { get;set; }
public DataKeyValue Value 
{ 
    get
    {
        return null;
    }
    set 
    { 
        Key = value; 
    }
}
```

This is the full class definition:

```
public class DataKeyWrapper
{
    public DataKey[] DataKEY { get;set; }
}
public class DataKey
{
    public DataKeyValue Key { get;set; }
    public DataKeyValue Value 
    { 
        get
        {
            return null;
        }
        set 
        { 
            Key = value; 
        }
    }
}
public class DataKeyValue
{
    public DateTime timestamp { get;set; }
    public Decimal value { get;set; }
}
```

The you can deserialize and re-serialize with this logic:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
...
var input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataKeyWrapper>(input);
var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input, new JsonSerializerSettings 
             {
                 Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, 
                 NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore 
             });
```

You can view a full fiddle on this here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YUsRn8

The Response:

```json
{
  "DataKEY": [
    {
      "Key": {
        "timestamp": "2022-10-26T05:00:00Z",
        "value": 0.0
      }
    },
    {
      "Key": {
        "timestamp": "2022-10-26T06:00:00Z",
        "value": 0.0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```