# I need to rearrange a JSON but I cant find a solution

Tags: c#, json

This is the JSON im receiving, already filtered. (its coming from the google places autocomplete API)

```
{
    "predictions": [
        {
            "description": "Frankfurt am Main, Deutschland",
            "place_id": "ChIJxZZwR28JvUcRAMawKVBDIgQ",
        },
        {
            "description": "Frankfurt (Oder), Deutschland",
            "place_id": "ChIJb_u1AiqYB0cRwDteW0YgIQQ",
        },
        {
            "description": "Frankfurt Hahn Flughafen (HHN), Lautzenhausen, Deutschland",
            "place_id": "ChIJX3W0JgQYvkcRWBxGlm6csj0",
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

And I need to get this JSON into this format:

```
{
   "success":true,
   "message":"OK",
   "data":[
      {
         "description":"Frankfurt Hahn Flughafen (HHN), Lautzenhausen, Deutschland",
         "id":"ChIJX3W0JgQYvkcRWBxGlm6csj0"
      },
      {
         "description":"Frankfurt Airport (FRA), Frankfurt am Main, Deutschland",
         "id":"ChIJeflCVHQLvUcRMfP4IU3YdIo"
      },
      {
         "description":"Frankfurt Marriott Hotel, Hamburger Allee, Frankfurt am Main, Deutschland",
         "id":"ChIJdag3xFsJvUcRZtfKqZkzBAM"
      }
   ]
}
I would be very g
```

So predictions is just renamed to "data", we change rename status to message, move it up and add a success if the http-request that happened earlier was a success or not. This does not seem so hard on the first catch, but I can't seem to find resources to transform or rearrange JSON in C#.

I would be very grateful for any tips or resources, so I can get unstuck on this probably not so difficult task. I should mention I'm fairly new to all of this.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Similar guidance to the comments in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74226455/1690217 It is much simpler to solve this via serialization.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is excactly what I was looking for. Seems like I cant properly google either :^)

Answer (score 0):

Just parse the origional json and move the data to the new json object

```
  var origJsonObj = JObject.Parse(json);

    var fixedJsonObj = new JObject {
    new JProperty("success",true),
    new JProperty("message",origJsonObj["status"]),
    new JProperty("data",origJsonObj["predictions"])
  };
```

it is not clear from your question what should be a success value, but I guess maybe you need this line too

```
if (fixedJsonObj["message"].ToString() != "OK") fixedJsonObj["success"] = false;
```

if you just need a fixed json

```
json = fixedJsonObj.ToString();
```

or you can create c# class (Data for example) and deserilize

```
Data result= fixedJsonObj.ToObject<Data>();
```

Comment: I like this, except I'd map `"message"` to `"status"` instead of hardcoding `"OK"`

Answer (score 0):

First create classes thats represent your jsons

```
public class Prediction
    {
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string place_id { get; set; }
    }

    public class InputJsonObj
    {
        public Prediction[] predictions { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }


    public class Datum
    {
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class OutPutJsoObj
    {
        public bool success { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
        public  OutPutJsoObj(){ 
         data = new List<Datum>();
        }
    }
```

Then  mapped objects (manually or using any of mapping libraries like AutoMapper) and create final json.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
InputJsonObj inputObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InputJsonObj >(inputJson);
OutPutJsoObj outObj = new OutPutJsoObj ();

foreach(var p in inputObj)
{
 outObj.Data.Add(new Datum() { descriptions = p.descriptions , id= p.place_id }
}
string outJson =  = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(outObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer from [@Serge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74305340/1690217) but if you're looking for a strongly typed approach we can model the input and output structure as the *same* set of classes and the output structure is similar, with the same relationships but only different or additional names this try this:

- The process used here [is described in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74305527/1690217) but effectively we create *write-only* properties that will receive the data during the deserialization process and will format it into the properties that are expected in the output.

```cs
public class ResponseWrapper
{
    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public bool Success { get;set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get;set; }
    [Obsolete("This field should not be used anymore, please use Message instead")]
    public string Status 
    { 
        get { return null; }
        set 
        { 
            Message = value; 
            Success = value.Equals("OK", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }
    }
    
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Prediction[] Data { get;set; }
    [Obsolete("This field should not be used anymore, please use Data instead")]
    public Prediction[] Predictions 
    { 
        get { return null; }
        set { Data = value; }
    }
}
public class Prediction
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string place_id { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize and re-serialize with this code:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
...
var input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseWrapper>(input);
var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objs, new JsonSerializerSettings 
             { 
                 Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, 
                 NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore 
             });
```

This is a fiddle you can test with: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DsI5Yc
And the output:

```json
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "OK",
  "data": [
    {
      "description": "Frankfurt am Main, Deutschland",
      "place_id": "ChIJxZZwR28JvUcRAMawKVBDIgQ"
    },
    {
      "description": "Frankfurt (Oder), Deutschland",
      "place_id": "ChIJb_u1AiqYB0cRwDteW0YgIQQ"
    },
    {
      "description": "Frankfurt Hahn Flughafen (HHN), Lautzenhausen, Deutschland",
      "place_id": "ChIJX3W0JgQYvkcRWBxGlm6csj0"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you were going to go to the trouble of writing a *converter* for the deserialization then I find this solution is a bit simpler. I tend to use this type of solution when exposing additional properties to allow *legacy* data to map into a the current code base.

- keeps the mapping and logic contained within the class
- tells developers still writing code against the deprecated structures about the change

> You can also augment this and implement a global converter to omit obsolete properties which would give you full backwards compatibility until you update the source to stop sending the legacy structure. This is a fiddle of such a solution: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MYXtGT
>
> - Inspired by these posts:
> - [JSON.Net Ignore Property during deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22616541/1690217)
> - [Is there a way to make JavaScriptSerializer ignore properties of a certain generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14510098/1690217)
> - [Exclude property from serialization via custom attribute (json.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13588192/1690217)
> - [Json.NET: Conditional Property Serialization](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ConditionalProperties.htm)